# Docker Rancher Cannot Force Remove

Tags: docker, rancher

installed Rancher on Docker locally and its loading on the localhost:8080. i wanted to delete the whole thing but i cannot stop it or force remove. using the command line:

```
sudo docker rm --force container_name
```

and i get back a error message:

```
Error response from daemon: Could not kill running container 35f959b60a0be31d706eb6592c2952783ec16994d398eb502ed9fd71e8050771, cannot remove - Cannot kill container 35f959b60a0be31d706eb6592c2952783ec16994d398eb502ed9fd71e8050771: rpc error: code = 7 desc = permission denied
```

ive been browsing around forums and the docs for both docker and rancher with no luck so far. im also more of a developer than a dev-op. Running on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first stop the container and then only you rm it

```
sudo docker stop container_name
sudo docker rm --force container_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, try force removing rancher image.

1. `sudo docker images`
2. Find image id for rancher and do `sudo docker rmi --force [id]`